# Xamarin 6.1.5 on OS El Capitan

Tags: xamarin, add-in, xamarin.mac

Hi I am beginner in C# coding and I just installed Xamarin Studio Community. With the 6.1.2 version I could go in the add-ins manager and look up for new add-ins. But since I updated to the 6.1.5 I got this error message when I go to the repository:

> Exception occurred: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not
>   Found.
>
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404)
>   Not Found.   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1025
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1037
>   at MonoDevelop.Core.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse
>   (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0008d] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3509/7494718e/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core.Web/RequestHelper.cs:194

It looks like the web page or the source doesn't exist. With the 6.1.2 it looks like it found the source to downloaded add-ins.

Any tips for what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried again since? Maybe the servers were temporarily having issues?

Comment: I tried a few times and just tried again and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. I would report it via:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/index.cgi